# Mouse click drags while released

Tags: windows-10, mouse-click

Sometimes when I use left mouse click (click and release) it drags whatever I clicked on.  It happens once every ~100 clicks or so. I have to click again to release.

I have win10 x64 bit, all drivers updated, mouse is Razer Abyssus. I have **unchecked** ClickLock box in Control Panel/Mouse.

Comment: Does a different mouse on the same computer have the same problem?

Comment: Clean your mouse. It's probably got a bit of a sticky button.

Comment: @music2myear  I don't have another mouse so I can't check it...

Comment: @DavidPostill It's clean, I thought of that too. The thing is, it clicks back after release, so if it would be a sticky button I'd notice if it wouldn't click back when releasing

Comment: Trying a different mouse is the next step in diagnosis. When dealing with mouse issues it is nearly always the mouse itself or the driver. Considering how inexpensive a basic functional mouse is, and the fact that everyone with a computer has one (or more), I recommend you try to gain access to another mouse to test.